# Eclipse showing new package inside existing package

Tags: eclipse, package

When I create a new package called `de.it2media.dps.statistics.client.application.buchanalysis`, it doesn't show it directly in the `src/main/java`folder as is shown below for the package `de.it2media.dps.statistics.client.application.home`, but it shows it inside an existing package of `de.it2media.dps.statisitcs.client.application`as shown below.

[image]

How do I make it not do that?

Comment: Is this the package explorer view? Is it in the correct place on your disc, and is it a regular directory? Does restarting or refreshing Eclipse change anything?

Comment: Yes it is the package explorer view and it is in the correct place. Restarting hasn't change anything,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen if the folder name contains characters invalid for a package name, like a dash `-` for instance. In your case the name is valid, so perhaps there is an exclusion pattern defined in build path. The one below would prevent your folder from being treated as a package.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes! The whole name of the package was an excluded pattern for some reason. Thanks!